# get value of an attribute by python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I want to get a "data-href" link from a button. I have used Selenium.I can successfully enter in my desired page but when I am trying to get the link from the button nothing happen,but throws an exception selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: 
I don't have any idea where I am going wrong.
my HTML:

```
<div class="lecture-attachment lecture-attachment-type-audio" 
         id="lecture-attachment-7274677">
   <div class="attachment-data"></div>


    <div class="audioloader" data-audioloader="AttachmentDrop" data- 
audioloader-name="ESLPod1103.mp3" data-audioloader-type="audio/mpeg" 
data-audioloader- 
url="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/Ius016cNTJmPRjUuCCp7" data- 
audioloader-initialized="true">
<div class="audioloader__placeholder">
   <button data- 
     href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/Ius016cNTJmPRjUuCCp7" 
     target="_blank" style="
     border: 0;
     outline: 0;
     background: transparent;
     cursor: pointer;
    ">
  <span class="audioloader__icon glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
  <span class="audioloader__name">ESLPod1103.mp3</span>
   </button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Python code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, \
WebDriverException
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/lmuser/chromedriver')
driver.get ("https://sso.teachable.com/secure/147717/users/sign_in? 
clean_login=true&reset_purchase_session=1")

driver.find_element_by_id("user_email").send_keys("***")
driver.find_element_by_id("user_password").send_keys("***")
driver.find_element_by_name("commit").click()
driver.get("https://tv.eslpod.com/courses/239156/lectures/3732329")
for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="lecture-attachment- 
7274677"]/div[2]/div/button'):
    print(i.get_attribute("data-href"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the number `7274677` in the html structure is not changing everytime you are executing the script.

If its not changing, Try the xpath:
`driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='lecture-attachment-7274677']//button")`

If its changing, Try the xpath:
`driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@id,'lecture-attachment')]//button")`

Comment: Happy to help you, though wanted to ask, was the id number getting changed or not?

Comment: id number didn't changed. btw how did you build the xpath for the button? I tried by right click on the tag and find Xpath for chrome.but as you it didn't worked. can you suggest me any resource for learning how to build xpath?

Comment: Honestly, have practiced it a lot from different websites and stackoverflow, though there is a tool named "chropath" for chrome browser which is a great tool to get the xpath, though it also gives some complex xpaths depending on the website you are using for automation.

Comment: You could have just used the css: `.lecture-attachment button` - simpler? Don't over-complicate these answers with xpath please.